# QuickBooks API no longer accepting my Access Token: token_rejected

Tags: oauth, go, intuit-partner-platform

I am connecting to the QB API using a Go library that I found for OAuth 1.0a: https://github.com/kurrik/oauth1a.  I actually had everything working, and I cannot think of anything that I changed, but now every request I make is returned with token_rejected.  From what I have read elsewhere, this usually means that my access token has expired, but even if I start the whole 3-legged OAuth process from the beginning I will get the same response as soon as I am verified.  I have triple-checked my consumer key and secret, I know they are correct.  I can plug in the Access Token and Secret created using the API Explorer into my code and it works just fine, so I know the problem is something related to the Access Token that I am getting back from QB. Everything looks OK when I print out the tokens that I am using, they do match what QB sends me back via the querystring after the handshake process.  I have been banging my head against the wall all day now, any help would be great.

Comment: Hi Blair, if the access token you get from the API Explorer works why do you narrow it down to the access token returned from Intuit, instead of a code issue? The API explorer does the same 3 legged flow as your code does. Does your access token that is rejected work in the API Explorer? if so, it sounds like an issue with the oauth library.

Comment: Either way, you would need to show your full XML request with headers for me to see if there is an issue there.

Comment: No, the tokens that I get back from Intuit in my app do NOT work in the API Explorer.  And as I said, I had this working a couple of days ago (which would suggest that the OAuth library I am using does work) and I definitely have not touched the code in the library.  I will gather up some XML for you and post it soon.  Thank you for the response.

Comment: Do the access tokens you get from the API Explorer work in the api explorer and in your app? Also, just curious what is the url you are using for the API Explorer? thanks

Comment: Yes, the tokens I get from the Explorer work in both places.  The url I am using is: https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO.

Comment: The request that I am attempting is just to get a list of customers, so I am not sending any XML to the API, I am sending a POST request to https://qbo.sbfinance.intuit.com/resource/customers/v2/REALMID (using my real realmid) with these headers:

Comment: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="qyprdNJsFjga1F4i3dgH3G3eQwBYRH", oauth_nonce="dcfff59cdb1ea8c7617679346e3bdb5d5b3e43eb", oauth_signature="F%2BUrnyEagzh3Y9c%2FWhBN0K4UHd0%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1370536268", oauth_token="qyprdWo6aW7OOzHhD4GJ8E39XHIFa8pkmWOJsLo5da5OVZeK", oauth_version="1.0"

Comment: And here is the response that I get back:  `code`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><FaultInfo xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd"><Message>Unauthorized OAuth Token: token_rejected</Message><ErrorCode>401</ErrorCode><Cause>SERVER</Cause></FaultInfo>`code`

Comment: Correction, I am currently posting to this URL: https://qbo.intuit.com/qbo1/resource/customers/v2/REALMID

Comment: I got it.  And I must say I've had an embarrassingly bad week of programming.  I totally changed the OAuth library code.  I don't remember doing it, but I must have.  I compared it to the original and there was one key line missing in the code that parsed the access token.

Comment: heh, we all have our moments :) glad you are all set now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding the answer, it was an issue with the Oauth Library code and is now resolved.

-Jarred

Comment: Technically, it was not an error with the OAuth library code... it was the fact that I had CHANGED the OAuth library code.  Had I left it alone in the first place, it would have worked fine.